# How to show Custom View on the top of the keyboard in react-native

Tags: react-native, keyboard, textinput

I am developing sample app, where I need a separate over which should be placed on the keyboard that appears when click on textInput.
I tried giving **absolute position, zIndex** everything but it is not worked.

*So can anyone tell me how to do that.*
I am doing this for custom keyboard some modules did not gave me correct once so I preferred this.

Answer (score 0):

Each platform - iOS / android - has its very specific APIs regarding Keyboard display, and customization.

The amount of customization you can do on existing keyboard is limited (ex: suggestion fields on top of the keyboard on iOS...), if you really want something specific, you might want to develop your own keyboard (look at https://github.com/reactnativecn/react-native-custom-keyboard the repo is 2 years old but might give you good inspiration, this other one is more recent : https://github.com/wix/react-native-keyboard-input)

Comment: Yes I have those module I don't want any default keyboard coming up but when using them for first time I am getting custom keyboard but when again focusing then the default keyboard is appearing.

Comment: https://github.com/reactnativecn/react-native-custom-keyboard  this repo is not at all working and its throwing build erros in ios and android